# Javascript problem: How do I change random color of heading from array of colors when hovering over div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a school project and stumbled upon this small issue:

When hovering over a div (with class .projects), I want the title (h1) tot change into one of three colors from an array, chosen randomly.

```
<h1>Some title</h1>
<div class="project"></div>



var colors = ["#F4A381", "#01ABA9", "#ffdc40"];
var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];


document.querySelector(".project").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  var title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
  title.style.color = randomColor;
});
```

My code in codepen:
https://codepen.io/BoLeynen/pen/XogLPy?editors=1010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Since `div` is empty so not sure where to hover. Secondly `getElementsByTagName` return a list so you need to get the element by passing the `index` & then get the randomColor inside the `mouseover` callback

```js
var colors = ["#F4A381", "#01ABA9", "#ffdc40"];
document.querySelector(".project").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  var title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  title.style.color = randomColor;
});
```

```html
<h1>Some title</h1>
<div class="project">hover here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array; i.e. it returns *all* elements with that tagname (the name hints this by using the plural `Elements`). Since you want to change the `style` property of just one element (i.e. the first one), the easiest thing to do is to add `[0]` when assigning the `title` variable.

Note that this will just change the color once, to a pre-chosen color from the list; I'm unclear if that's the desired behavior or if you want to change it every time the mouse is hovered.

```js
var colors = ["#F4A381", "#01ABA9", "#ffdc40"];
var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

document.querySelector(".project").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  var title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  title.style.color = randomColor;
});
```

```css
.project{background:red;height:100px;width:100px}
```

```html
<h1>Some title</h1>
<div class="project"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")` to `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]`.

Because, the **getElementsByTagName** selector return an collection so the style not support in whole collection that why your code not working.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the other answers you `getElementsByTagName` returns a array-like structure. You need to extract a specific element in order to manipulate its style property.

Presuming you mean to be changing the color every time you mouse over the relevant section, you will need to do your `Math.random` *inside* the event handler for the mouseover event. Otherwise it will just be computed once, when the script first evaluates and then never changed.

On the idea that you might mean to make *all* `h1`s change color (otherwise `getElementsByTagName` seems a weird inclusion since you've already demonstrated `querySelector`) I just added a `forEach` with the random color being determined for each `h1` tag.

```js
var colors = ["#F4A381", "#01ABA9", "#ffdc40"];

document.querySelector(".project").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  var titles = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("h1"));
  titles.forEach(function(title){
    var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    title.style.color = randomColor;
  });
});
```

```css
.project{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some title</h1>
<!--This should change color,,-->

<div class="project"></div>
<!--when hovering over this div. -->
```